# Is it possible to export Android OS data to iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, android

Is there any way to export Android Data to an iPhone?

I got an old Android Phone, i want  to throw it away but i got very important data in it. **Is there anyway to send that data directly into my iPhone 6s?** Because i don't want to loose that data and i also don't want to have that android phone. Which software can help me in transferring data from Android to iOS?

I have got several things as my important data:

> Pictures, Videos and Contacts

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an [app in the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios) and a [support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196) describing the required steps in details.

There's a nice page for switchers as well - https://www.apple.com/switch/ the one thing to pay attention to if you don't appreciate the marketing is the help from a live person through @AppleSupport and the Support App you can download on iOS once you've got your phone running. Try to transfer all the data within a day of getting your phone so you don't have two sets of photos and documents if you start making some on iPhone before you get everything over from the old phone.

Answer (score -1):

Apple has made an app for that (it is WiFi based)

[image]

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196